# Serial type not working on postgres when creating a Domain?

Tags: postgresql

I have run into a strange problem with Postgres 9 on Mac OS X, I have the following statement which works on Windows Postgres but on on Mac OS postgres

CREATE DOMAIN pkey_domain AS SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;

returns

ERROR:  type "serial" does not exist

*** *Error* *****

ERROR: type "serial" does not exist
SQL state: 42704

SERIAL is a data type that is supported by postgres why am I not able to create a Domain with it? Does the deafult installer on the Mac not create the type?

Comment: I just tested on PC and I have the same error so it is not a MAC only issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serial isn't really a type, it is a kind of macro that creates the sequence for you, sets the default value of the column, etc. It is not referenced in pg_type. So you can't use it like this.

Comment: +1 and here is a [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) to the docs

Comment: are there any alternatives to get what I want, I really want all my tables to have same surrogate keys and domain seems the right way to do it, I don't want to have to create the sequences by hand seems like lots of typing for no good reason.

Comment: "SERIAL PRIMARY KEY" is too much typing ? It creates the sequences automatically for you.

Comment: I would like to use domain if possible, I was referring to defining my own domain which acts the same as serial.